# Dropbox API does not update access level

Tags: java, permissions, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

The `Dropbox API for Java` offers the following approach for modifying the permissions of an existing file collaboration:

```
public static void updateFileMember(DbxVlientV2 client, String file, String email, AccessLevel level) throws Exception {
  MemberSelector member = MemberSelector.email(email);
  MemberAccessResult result = client.sharing().updateFileMember(file, member, level);
}
```

However, running the above method for changing the access level from VIEWER to EDITOR, results in this error:

```
Exception in 2/sharing/update_file_member: “no permission” (user message: you don’t have permissions perform this action.)
```

The same error appears for removing a file collaboration and adding it again (API `2/sharing/add_file_member`). Adding a new collaboration without having removed it earlier on, works as expected.

The application via which the API is invoked, has `Full Dropbox` (as opposed to only `App Folder`) access.

Is there any other way of authorizing the app to allow programmatic changes to the access level of a file, elevating it to EDITOR?

Comment: *user message: you don’t have permissions perform this action* log in as a user that does have permission to update.

Comment: The user is an owner for all the files and the app has full access to the Dropbox account.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed to [Dropbox API Support](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/bd-p/101000014)

Comment: How so? StackOverflow has many Dropbox questions. The idea for asking here is that I may be missing something. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file sharing functionality offered by [addFileMember](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#addFileMember-java.lang.String-java.util.List-) and [updateFileMember](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#updateFileMember-java.lang.String-com.dropbox.core.v2.sharing.MemberSelector-com.dropbox.core.v2.sharing.AccessLevel-) does not support [`AccessLevel.editor`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/AccessLevel.html#EDITOR).

If you want to add editors to a file, put the file in a folder and share the folder via [`shareFolder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#shareFolder-java.lang.String-), [`addFolderMember`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#addFolderMember-java.lang.String-java.util.List-), and [`updateFolderMember`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/DbxUserSharingRequests.html#updateFolderMember-java.lang.String-com.dropbox.core.v2.sharing.MemberSelector-com.dropbox.core.v2.sharing.AccessLevel-).

(Aside: apologies this isn't more clearly documented. This is due to the [`AccessLevel`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/AccessLevel.html) object itself being shared with other methods which do support [`AccessLevel.editor`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/sharing/AccessLevel.html#EDITOR). I'll ask the team to clarify this in the documentation.)

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully file-level support for AccessLevel.EDITOR will be added soon.